# Tkinter Menu Bar Vertical Dot Separator

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following image 
[image]

Is there any way I can realize the same "vertical dot separator" in python with tkinter? If not what python gui library will have this feature? The only menu bar separator I know it's the "add_separator()" method from the Menu Class of tkinter.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything like that ready-made, but you could always add a Label containing an image of the dots, or a Canvas containing a vertical line with a stipple pattern applied.  If you are expecting the separator to have any functionality (such as "drag to rearrange"), that's considerably more complicated, and I'd have to suggest looking for another GUI toolkit that supports that functionality natively.

Comment: Thank you for your response, can you suggest some gui library that would have that "drag to rearrange" functionality, that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to do this on a menubar, you can create a do-nothing command with either an image or a unicode character.

[image]

For example:

```
menubar.add_command(label="\u22EE",
                    activebackground=menubar.cget("background"))
```

Comment: I tried the following line of code "menu.add_command(label = "\u22EE", activebackground = menu.cget("background"))" but I will have the following output in the menubar "\u22EE" instead of the separator... maybe cause I have python 2.7?

Comment: Nevermind I just had to add "u" before the unicode, thank you for your response! The line of code looks like this: menu.add_command(label = u"\u22EE", activebackground = menu.cget("background"))